# Isinst opcode returns null value when it shouldn't

Tags: .net, cil, opcode

recently I have overwritten sysglobl.dll in the GAC by adding IL code to one of the functions in CultureDefinition Class, so the the .net framework and visual studio load the changed dll directly from GAC.
The function is:
*System.Globalization.CalendarId CalendarIdofCalendar(System.Globalization.Calendar)*
here is the code from ildasm tool.

```
IL_0077:  ldarg.0  
IL_0078:  isinst     [mscorlib]System.Globalization.KoreanCalendar  
IL_007d:  brfalse.s  IL_0081  
IL_007f:  ldc.i4.5  
IL_0080:  ret  
IL_0081:  ldarg.0  
IL_0082:  isinst     [mscorlib]System.Globalization.HijriCalendar  
IL_0087:  brfalse.s  IL_008b  
IL_0089:  ldc.i4.6  
IL_008a:  ret
```

> The Added Code

```
    IL_008b:  ldarg.0  
IL_008c:  isinst     [mscorlib]System.Globalization.PersianCalendar  
IL_0091:  brfalse.s  IL_0096  
IL_0093:  ldc.i4.s   22  
IL_0095:  ret
```

> End Of Added Code

```
IL_0096:  ldarg.0  
IL_0097:  isinst     [mscorlib]System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar  
IL_009c:  brfalse.s  IL_00a1  
IL_009e:  ldc.i4.s   23  
IL_00a0:  ret  
IL_00a1:  ldstr      "CustomCaledarsNotSupported"  
IL_00a6:  call       string   System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder::GetResourceString(string)  
IL_00ab:  newobj     instance void  [mscorlib]System.NotSupportedException::.ctor(string)    
IL_00b0:  throw
```

now here is the problem at line

```
__IL_008c: isinst [mscorlib]System.Globalization.PersianCalendar__
```

when i pass an instance of PersianCalendar *isinst* returnS null value so the function will throw NotSupportedException. but if i pass HijriCalendar it work fine and will go to 
line

```
**IL_0089: ldc.i4.6**
```

and so on.

i cannot find the reason why the part i have added wont works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you add/modify in which class(es)?

Comment: And most importantly, why? Why didn't you just write normal C# code in your own class library? Why are you monkeypatching the .NET runtime assemblies at all?

Comment: the code where supposed to be in bold sry,as i mention at the post, the class is CultureDefinition from sysglobl.dll and the function is CalendarIdofCalendar, and the reason:
cultureinfo doesnt accept custom calendars and microsoft implemented optional calendars wrongly for fa-IR culture, and there is no persiancalendar. its years that microsoft knows abt it and they just dont fx it :(

Comment: Have you refreshed the NGEN cache? Not sure it is needed but depends on how exactly you rebuilt that assembly.

Comment: This is really unsupportable if you want to distribute your application. If you know the ID to return already, just wrap the call to CalendarIdofCalendar and check the type, and return 22.

Comment: Yeah, he'd have to work hard to convince users of his application to swap out core parts of the .NET runtime just to make his application work.

Comment: i've found the problem, the file sysglobl.ni.dll from X64 bit folder of nativeassembly in GAC was the problem, i removed that and now the code works. @codekaizen i am calling the function directly form my code, its been called in different places, and the program is using 3 diff culture so all of the culture must works.

Comment: @TPECI - I suspected as much, however, I'd still look into abstracting any call to it via some explicit calls using CultureInfo. You'll be much, _much_ better off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you making the change? The code itself looks good, my guess is that the metadata tables or other metadata info are getting confused so the `[mscorlib]System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` token doesn't actually refer to what it should, or that the actual assembly isn't getting called appropriately.

Comment: i found the reason , i needed to delete sysglobl.ni.dll from 64-bit framework, i already deleted 32 bit one but not the 64 bit.